# SSIS installation failed due to SSISOneDesigner2012.msi installation failure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

In "Manage Extensions" in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.9 on Windows 10 Enterprise, I found that choose "SQL Server Integration Services Projects" (version 3.16) to download and install.

During the set up in its installation, I have the following errors in the log file:

```
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:47]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {DB97C76B-9116-42C5-8814-0041856EB9E6}, version: 11.4.7001.0, package: SSISOneDesigner2012
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:47]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 2012 (id: SSISOneDesigner2012)
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:47]i301: Applying execute package: SSISOneDesigner2012, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DB97C76B-9116-42C5-8814-0041856EB9E6}v11.4.7001.0\payload\SSISOneDesigner2012.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]e000: Error 0x80070652: Failed to install MSI package.
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]e000: Error 0x80070652: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]e000: Error 0x80070652: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 2012 (id: SSISOneDesigner2012)
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i319: Applied execute package: SSISOneDesigner2012, result: 0x80070652, restart: None
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]e000: Error 0x80070652: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 2012 (id: SSISOneDesigner2012)
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i318: Skipped rollback of package: SSISOneDesigner2012, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 2012 (id: SSISOneDesigner2012)
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i319: Applied rollback package: SSISOneDesigner2012, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {DB97C76B-9116-42C5-8814-0041856EB9E6}, package: SSISOneDesigner2012
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i351: Removing cached package: SSISOneDesigner2012, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DB97C76B-9116-42C5-8814-0041856EB9E6}v11.4.7001.0\
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i351: Removing cached package: VSTA2019, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\49D0F2156CFF76DFDCA97FD5C3CD7CEB1CEDABFC\
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i351: Removing cached package: VCRedist2010, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\28C54491BE70C38C97849C3D8CFBFDD0D3C515CB\
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i326: Removed dependency: {b7340964-f5aa-4346-b7a0-999d89f82e55} on package provider: ISVsixPostInstall, package ISVsixPostInstall
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Projects Post Install (id: ISVsixPostInstall)
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i301: Applying rollback package: ISVsixPostInstall, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\70FE37A74F0B73AC666C42193E2CAC1090C03C5F\ISVsixPostInstall.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\70FE37A74F0B73AC666C42193E2CAC1090C03C5F\ISVsixPostInstall.exe" /instanceIds:"e655e95a" /log:"C:\Users\C314737\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20220421100806_2_ISVsixPostInstall.log" /u'
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Projects Post Install (id: ISVsixPostInstall)
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i319: Applied rollback package: ISVsixPostInstall, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i329: Removed package dependency provider: ISVsixPostInstall, package: ISVsixPostInstall
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i351: Removing cached package: ISVsixPostInstall, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\70FE37A74F0B73AC666C42193E2CAC1090C03C5F\
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i326: Removed dependency: {b7340964-f5aa-4346-b7a0-999d89f82e55} on package provider: ISVsix, package ISVsix
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Projects (id: ISVsix)
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:19:50]i301: Applying rollback package: ISVsix, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7\VSIXBootstrapper.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7\VSIXBootstrapper.exe" /q /admin /instanceIds:"e655e95a" /logFile:"C:\Users\C314737\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20220421100806_1_ISVsix.log" /u:851E7A09-7B2B-4F06-A15D-BABFCB26B970'
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:22:55]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Projects (id: ISVsix)
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:22:55]i319: Applied rollback package: ISVsix, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:22:55]i329: Removed package dependency provider: ISVsix, package: ISVsix
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:22:55]i351: Removing cached package: ISVsix, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7\
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:22:55]i326: Removed dependency: {b7340964-f5aa-4346-b7a0-999d89f82e55} on package provider: ISVsixPreInstall, package ISVsixPreInstall
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:22:55]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Projects Pre Install (id: ISVsixPreInstall)
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:22:55]i301: Applying rollback package: ISVsixPreInstall, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\68E7C6C068B59716CFFAACDFCD1B26E0D55ADD6F\ISVsixPreInstall.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\68E7C6C068B59716CFFAACDFCD1B26E0D55ADD6F\ISVsixPreInstall.exe" /instanceIds:"e655e95a" /log:"C:\Users\C314737\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20220421100806_0_ISVsixPreInstall.log" /u'
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:22:56]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Projects Pre Install (id: ISVsixPreInstall)
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:22:56]i319: Applied rollback package: ISVsixPreInstall, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:22:56]i329: Removed package dependency provider: ISVsixPreInstall, package: ISVsixPreInstall
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:22:56]i351: Removing cached package: ISVsixPreInstall, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\68E7C6C068B59716CFFAACDFCD1B26E0D55ADD6F\
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:22:56]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall progress: 100
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:22:56]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {b7340964-f5aa-4346-b7a0-999d89f82e55}
[2FB0:1860][2022-04-21T10:22:56]i352: Removing cached bundle: {b7340964-f5aa-4346-b7a0-999d89f82e55}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{b7340964-f5aa-4346-b7a0-999d89f82e55}\
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:22:56]e000: MainViewModel: AnotherInstallRunning not found.
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:22:56]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: 
[0464:3DAC][2022-04-21T10:22:56]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070652, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[0464:12A8][2022-04-21T10:25:23]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\C314737\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20220421100806.log
[0464:12A8][2022-04-21T10:28:07]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\C314737\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20220421100806.log
[0464:12A8][2022-04-21T11:08:24]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\C314737\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20220421100806.log
```

What can I do to solve the problem? I googled around, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: You can check if SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio are installed : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: *"Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 2012"* sounds suspicious, as does the version (11.4.7001.0); the current version of the [SQL Server Integration Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects) extension is 3.16.

Comment: @larnu, it is a prerequisites to enable SSIS Tools. Have many issues with SSIS tools, and installing of force reinstalling these tools worked for me.